# Are off-topic political rants encouraged in answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

In response to [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/184893/team-member-regularly-ignores-back-to-office-policy), user [computercarguy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/74517/computercarguy) posted [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/184893/team-member-regularly-ignores-back-to-office-policy/184919#184919).

As pointed out in the comments (including John Goodrow's comment, currently with 11 upvotes), this answer contains an off-topic political rant. I flagged the answer as such, but my flag was declined.

Can the moderator who did so explain why they declined the flag? Are off-topic political rants encouraged in Workplace SE answers?

Comment: That was me, it didn't seem ranty enough to discard the whole answer. No we don't encourage political rants, but it has 11 upvotes and downvotes. So must have some merit. I don't understand the political references myself but I failed to find any harm or malice in it.

Comment: @Kilisi "I failed to find any harm or malice in it." I find that hard to believe. What does the one-paragraph rant about conservatives, for example, have to do with answering the question?

Comment: There was also an attempt to edit out a paragraph. If 11 people upvote, and 11 downvote, then I take that as having some merit. I personally don't think it's a good answer. Lots of answers have bits that are not directly relevant. And I have no idea what a conservative is.

Comment: @Kilisi "There was also an attempt to edit out a paragraph." Correct. An off-topic paragraph that has nothing to do with the question, as many users agree. So why did you decline the flag?

Comment: @Kilisi "I have no idea what a conservative is." I also find that hard to believe.

Comment: Why hard to believe? It's true enough. I'm on an independent Polynesian Island, overseas politics to me are just crooks in suits... each as bad as the other... no offence

Comment: @Kilisi Please answer the question.

Comment: I have, but if you disbelieve my answers, it seems pointless.

Comment: @Kilisi You have not explained why you declined to remove the off-topic political rant that has nothing to do with answering the question. That does not require "discarding the whole answer".

Comment: Because I didn't see a need, nor did anyone else who reviewed it I assume. I would never mess with someones answer without good reason.

Comment: There is a difference between *encouraged* and *tolerated*.  Also, the whole purpose of the voting system is to mark out answers that the community perceives as *wrong* in one way or another.

Comment: I don't see the need for your rather abusive tone and demands towards the moderators.  Also, you have been a member for six years and 10 months, and have a 101 rep?  Are you just here to cause trouble?

Comment: So, just to be clear, is your objection to political rants in general, or just conservatives?  It seems that that word has put a bee in your bonnet

Comment: I have deleted the paragraph about conservatives. I think the paragraph is actually pretty inflammatory. I can perfectly accept that @Kilisi with maybe a lesser understanding of US politics may not see it.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter I don't understand your question, or your rude tone.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie computercarguy reverted your edit. Seems like they're adamant in keeping the off-topic political rant.

Comment: It's pretty much the only part I have a real problem with. I edited, and explained the rationale. They decided to revert, which is their right.

Comment: @user76284 I'm not even matching your tone towards Kilisi.  Might I also point out that the exact same thing is happening to your question posted here?  Should we delete this because it's controversial and political in nature?  The voting system works, and for the most part, we want to leave things alone.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter "I'm not even matching your tone towards Kilisi." Right. You're being extremely rude and I'm not. "the exact same thing is happening to your question posted here" What is? "it's... political in nature" Nonsense.

Comment: @user76284 I'm being blunt not rude.  You came in here demanding answers, then grilling Kilisi.  You also questioned his veracity, in saying "I find that hard to believe", You derided his reasoning, demanded he answer your question when he already did, and were borderline abusive towards him.  I will refrain from voicing my opinion about your overall behavior as I have have no desire to earn a suspension, and it would be richly earned.  You've been mostly dormant for nearly seven years and chose to make your big entrance for the sole purpose of pestering a mod.  Somewhat sus....

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter "You came in here demanding answers" I came here *asking* for answers. Do you know what a question and answer site is for? "I find that hard to believe" That's true. Why would a moderator who "has no idea what a conservative is" intervene in this matter instead of leaving it to someone who does? "demanded he answer your question when he already did" He did not answer the question. Try reading the conversation again. "were borderline abusive towards him" Nonsense. That's a pure invention on your part. "it would be richly earned" More nonsense. You're projecting your own malice.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter "You've been mostly dormant for nearly seven years" So? How I spend my personal time is none of your business. Attacking someone for *not* participating on a site? Madness. "chose to make your big entrance" What dramatic language for asking a question. Absolutely ridiculous. "for the sole purpose of pestering a mod" You're out of your mind. Here, try reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Do you know what the duties of a moderator are? Do you know what Meta is for? Hint: It's for asking questions to the community and the moderators.

Answer (score 4):

I declined the flag because I didn't see a need to do anything.

One portion of the answer does seem a bit ranty but against no one in particular. There is a comprehensive answer in it as well. So I gave it the benefit of the doubt despite not particularly liking the answer.

We don't encourage political or other rants, but this was not extreme and may have been included as contrast. Deleting that portion would clearly conflict with the authors intent. There is a difference between encouraging and tolerating as a commenter pointed out.

As a moderator, I try and use a light touch unless there are personal attacks or similar going on. I didn't see that so I let it stand.

With your paragraph deletion attempt, that's a totally different issue from any flags. But that was me as well. I came across it while doing the review queues, and the edit clearly went against the authors intent so I rejected it. Nothing to do with my mod status. I do the edit request queues every time I log in, anyone else with a bit of rep can do the queues any time.

Comment: With all due respect, the relevant portions of the answer clearly touched on hot button issues that may be apparent only to someone with knowledge of the current US political situation.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I understand that, I was just answering why I declined the flag. I don't take flags lightly.

Comment: I was trying to point out why you should have let other mods make that decision, IMHO. Anyway, the deed is done.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Perhaps.... my judgement isn't perfect, done now though. I've learnt something at least.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere is there an American mod?

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter - (shrug) I don't know where most of the mods live.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter I like American movies if that counts... Clint Eastward ones

Comment: @Kilisi I'd really love to see how America is seen in the rest of the world.  I think that all the culture that leaks out into the rest of the world is based out of New York, Los Angeles, and a distorted view of Texas.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter any country is distorted until you've lived there 20 years and actively studied the place. US is probably too big to get through thoroughly in a lifetime though... I have no ambitions on ever going there

Comment: Yeah, 50 states, all with their sub cultures.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter America is a continent, and I do live in America... hehehe... (it's a strong pet peeve for us in Central America/Latin America to hear or see USA being called "Muricah"... but yeah USA is quite big and several sub-cultures I reckon)

Comment: @DarkCygnus Yeah, but we are the only ones who have "America" in our name.  But yes, there are several territories not on the continent.  Including Hawaii.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO any discussion about COVID draws out political rants (at least in the US), and the answer and comments show how. The answer should have been scrubbed or deleted. Other answers should be scrubbed or deleted as well.

Comment: COVID is a tender subject anywhere, but I didn't see any lines crossed. If the community wants it deleted, they can 'Vote to delete' no rationalisation or mod intervention necessary.

Comment: That answer is at the absolute bottom, and I've seen far more political answers stand, nasty comments as well.

Comment: Also, that user has been here for six years, and has contributed virtually nothing, but a few comments, and now leads with a rant about conservative politics?  He was here when the pronoun PD were throwing their weight around, why was he quiet then.  I suspect that this user is trolling

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter - could be trolling. I don't know. I do know that COVID questions and answers are doomed to bring out the worst. They should all be scrubbed or deleted. The question and answers would be better without that irrelevant factoid, IMHO. I removed the COVID reference from the question. Apparently someone decided to put it back.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter - rather than get into an edit war over the question and answers, **I voted to delete the question. I'd encourage others to do the same.**

Comment: Well, that's an issue of maturity more than the disease, and the general tone of debate has degenerated to the point of mud slinging.  The trolling tactic is to make issues so volitile as to make them impossible to discuss.  Deleting the question is giving in to that tactic

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter Who are you talking about? I think you have confused me with someone else. Where did I "rant about conservative politics"? I'm doing the opposite: I'm pointing out that a rant about conservatives in another user's answer is off-topic.

Comment: @user76284 you are not new here.  It is my opinion that you are trying to stir the pot.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter I'm pointing out an off-topic rant in an answer that has nothing to do with answering the question. Other users agree. How is that "trying to stir the pot"?

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter What does being "new here" have to do with anything?

Comment: Joe, your delete vote won't work because answer has positive score. And trusted users can't cast more delete votes because of that. At current vote split +17/-16 it looks like it has got bunch of upvotes from hot questions visitors who are entertained by rants as usual

Comment: @gnat - I vote only when I feel a question should definitely be closed. I don't do that often. I don't worry about if it will "work" or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't particularity like XY answers that deliberately go against explicit requests of the question. I also don't like particularity ranty answers either.

I'd categorise the answer as both.

But on the flip side, I think it's far superior for people to have their say in a ranty answer, that sort of at least mildly addresses the question, than pollute all the answers they disagree with, with comments. At least the community can self-moderate that answer, and the answerer may think of a way to present their point of view in a less caustic manner to not get their point of view downvoted to oblivion.

For example, the author of that question started commenting on my answer basically attacking the premise of the question. I basically said that if they've got an answer, they should just answer themselves. And to their credit they did.

(And for the record, I don't particularly like [nvoigt's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/184896/59502) either. The question has been nicely cleaned up to be a bit less... inflammatory, but I suspect some answers deserve a similar treatment.)

However, what I don't think is useful, and indeed is malicious, are attacks on people on one part of the political spectrum.

There is fundamentally no need for it, it causes disruption, and to perhaps more widely visible answers, would cause more heat than light.

I agree with @user76284 here. I have attempted to edit out the offensive elements of the answer, but my changes have been reverted. So, I will reflag the answer because that is the proper thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since my answer has come up here directly and indirectly here is my take on it:

From my point of view there is a big difference between judgemental texts about politics (which I'm certainly guilty of, too, don't get me wrong, just not in that topic) and citing facts that people of a certain political direction mainly in the US will dispute and call them "offensive".

The answer in question here contains a text that is simply wrong. Neither the question nor the answer have a specific country tag and as such, saying "the conservatives" *did something* is wrong. In my country, they did not. In many other countries they did not. In the US that is probably correct, but then it needs to be tagged that way or actually specified as in saying "the GOP" or "the Republicans".

On the other hand, my answer just states facts. Not obscure conspiracy theories or opinion. You can put it into google and get charts for it in the first hit. From the CDC or from my countries authority on it, that reports it's number to the CDC to get a global view. I disagree with the notion that I would be responsible for the nutjobs that don't believe in facts. And I don't care that US politics has been and continues to be that carwreck of a burning clown car for the past 5 years. I will not cater to the smallest possible "agreeable truth" on the internet. I'm sure most of what I believe in is giving people like Margerie Taylor Greene rashes. And they would love to pour comments into the internet how wrong I am. But we cannot give in to those people. This is an international site and I will not dumb down my posts until a pillow CEO overseas can agree with them.

Also, why is the number of comments a post creates a reason to change it or close it or even delete it? It isn't. If the comments are a problem, disable them. If arguing in comments is a problem (that I certainly have been guilty off, too, just not in that topic), then warn people and suspend people. But voting to close/delete or forcefully edit a post because you don't like the comments *from others* it generates is not what this site is build on.

I think it was a pretty normal Workplace question, until at some point it probably hit HNQ, because it was fine for a day or two and suddenly all kinds of weirdos flooded in. And I mean it, if you read through the comments, I am supposed to be wrong on numbers that you can google and people didn't read past the first paragraph only to tell me I'm wrong and they are right *and this came from both sides*. I'm sorry, but I cannot be expected to write posts that do not make random internet trolls post their weird shit. If that is a problem (and I would not disagree) then take it off the HNQ. I don't need twitter fame and random trolls.  But I do need to be able to post an answer without some of *us* trying to change or delete it.

Comment: I mostly agree. It IS an international site. I wouldn't make an exception for my own country if it ever comes up. I don't see why the US should be treated as a special case.... no offence intended to US people. In terms of mod intervention. For the rest the community individuals are free to downvote, vote to delete or anything else in their toolbox without hindrance for any reason or no reason as they see fit. I couldn't justify messing with that, it's fundamental to the site.

Comment: Just for the record, I'm not disputing what you've presented as facts. I'm disputing their relevance. If Alice has reasons, then as you rightly pointed out, she should address those reasons. Maybe they are COVID related. Maybe they are not. People will always find ways to argue facts (as well as "facts"), and with this particularity divisive topic, if you can avoid opening a can of worms, why wouldn't you.

Comment: I mean, by choosing to post COVID facts, for no reason, you're really inviting all the "weirdos" to dispute parts of your answer, than don't really matter in the grand scheme of things. I'm not sure what you're expecting mods to do. Basically do their own research and delete the comments which are factually wrong?

Comment: I don't expect the mods to do anything at all, except move to chat and comment lock when people don't listen. What I *don't* want, is that the question or answer are changed, based on how many trolls comment. If the comments are a problem, tackle the problem.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm not saying the comments are the problem. I'm saying the answer is the problem (because it contains pointless information).

Comment: I'm always surprised how other people determine what is and isn't pointless in my own answer. I already told you, I would have written a different answer if this weren't a back-from-work after COVID in a time were COVID is still active. You may think the answer would have been *the same* without COVID, *I don't*. Without COVID around, my answer would have been different. That is why you are free to write your own answer and I would like to keep mine as it is.

Comment: @nvoigt You literally say in your answer "I would assume she has a good reason to not show." Which means that the whole COVID spiel you went on with is irrelevant. I don't understand why you'd go to do much effort to attempt to justify a particular reason, and then tell us to trust on face value that Alice has a good reason, which may be completely different. Did you mean to say that we should assume that Alice has the same reason that you present?

Comment: Yes, if someone does not return to pre-COVID workplaces in COVID times, I will make the educated guess and say: that has to do with COVID. Could it be something else? Sure. Maybe she was abducated by aliens. I cannot rule that out. But I think COVID is a  valid guess, as good as any guess we constantly make here.